# How to get the digits of int value in Golang

Tags: go, golang-migrate

How can we get the digits of `num := 658943` in Golang? I need to print each digit value from the given number (`num`) as integer instead of string.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var (
        num    = 68932
        digits []int
    )

    // do something with num, insert the result to digits

    for _, val := range digits {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

// expected output
// 6
// 8
// 9
// 3
// 2
```

Comment: What does it mean to iterate an int value?

Comment: "I tried But, no luck" tried what? What went wrong? Show your code and describe the problem.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you look into it once, please?

Comment: `num % 10` returns the last digit. `(num / 10) % 10` returns the second last digit etc. Convert this logic to a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strconv`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    var (
        num    = 68932
        digits []int
    )

    s := strconv.Itoa(num)

    for _, n := range s {
        digits = append(digits, int(n-'0'))
    }

    for _, val := range digits {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AHzwHPd7GJC